# Validating and submitting a web page composed of dynamic tabs containing each of them a form (submitting a set of nested forms with a single click)

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I am working on project with ASP.NET MVC 5 (C #), AngularJS 1.6, HTML5, Bootstrap 3.3, and SQL Server 2014. I am facing a problem of validation and submitting of a web page composed of dynamic tabs containing each of them a form. I want to verify the validity of each form (contained in a tab), and then submit all the forms in one "Send" button click to be saved in the SQL Server database.

How can I do that? (I have an idea to put the set of forms in a list of forms, but I do not know how to do it  (I saw that I could use the ng-form contained in form and use REST Web API).

I give you an example to fully understand my need and help me if possible by telling me the types of variables and the steps to follow for the front-end and back-end.

SupportDemande.cshtml :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsJS/SupportDemande/SupportDemandeApp.js"></script>

<div ng-app="supportDemandeApp" ng-controller="supportDemandeCtrl" class="supportDemande" role="tabpanel" ng-cloak>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" tabindex="selectedIndex">
        <li class="active" role="presentation" ng-repeat="revue in revues" ng-click="selectRevue($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedRevue == $index}">
            <a data-target="#revue" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="revue">
                Revue {{revue.id}}
                <span ng-click="supprimerRevue($index)" ng-if="$index > 0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="tab-content" id="revueListe" name="revueListe" ng-model="revueListe" method="post" ng-submit="submitSupportDemande()" novalidate="">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="revue" ng-model="revue">
            <revue-tab ng-model="revueTab"></revue-tab>
        </div>
    </form>

    <br /> <br /> <br />
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="annuler" name="annuler">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="envoyer" name="envoyer" style="margin-left:10px" ng-disabled="!validSupportDemande()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RevueTabTemplate.html :

```
    <ng-form class="form-horizontal" id="revueForm" name="revueForm" ng-model="revueForm" method="post" ng-submit="submitRevueForm()" novalidate="">
    <br />
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Données de la revue</b></legend>

        <div style="padding:25px;margin-top:-30px;margin-bottom:-10px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomDemandeur" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomDemandeur" name="nomDemandeur" ng-model="nomDemandeur" required />
                    <div class="help-block col-lg-9" ng-messages="revueForm.nomDemandeur.$error" ng-if="revueForm.nomDemandeur.$touched">
                        <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="prenomDemandeur" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenomDemandeur" name="prenomDemandeur" ng-model="prenomDemandeur" required />
                    <div class="help-block col-lg-9" ng-messages="revueForm.nomDemandeur.$error" ng-if="revueForm.nomDemandeur.$touched">
                        <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': revueForm.emailDemandeur.$touched && revueForm.emailDemandeur.$invalid }">
                <label for="emailDemandeur" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailDemandeur" name="emailDemandeur" ng-model="emailDemandeur" required />
                    <div class="help-block col-lg-9" ng-messages="revueForm.emailDemandeur.$error" ng-if="revueForm.emailDemandeur.$touched">
                        <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                        <span ng-message="email">Invalid Email</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="ajouterRevue()" ng-disabled="!validSupportDemande()">Add a revue</button>
        <button class="remove btn btn-danger" style="margin-left:10px" ng-click="supprimerRevue($index)" ng-disabled="$index > 0"><!--ng-if="$last"-->Delete this revue</button>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

SupportDemandeApp.js :

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular.min.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js" />

var supportDemandeApp = angular.module('supportDemandeApp', ['ngMessages']);

supportDemandeApp.directive('revueTab',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: '/ScriptsJS/SupportDemande/RevueTabTemplate.html'
        }
    }
);

supportDemandeApp.controller('supportDemandeCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, revueService) {
    var serv = revueService.getAll();
    serv.then(function (d) {
        supportDemandeCtrl(d.data, $scope, $filter);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
    })
});

//Service Tabs
supportDemandeApp.service('revueService', function ($http) {
    this.getAll = function () {
        return $http
            ({
                url: "/Supports/SupportDemande/RevueData", //Here we are calling our controller JSON action  
                method: "GET"
            });
    };
});

supportDemandeApp.controller('supportDemandeCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', supportDemandeCtrl]);

function supportDemandeCtrl(data, $scope, $filter) {

//Fonctions d'onglets Revues
var revuesArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    revuesArray.push(
        {
            'title': "Revue ID: " + data[i].RevueID,
            'content': data[i].RevueContent
            //'content': $scope.revueTab
        });
}
var revues = revuesArray,
    selected = null,
    previous = null;
$scope.revues = revues;
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
$scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function (current, old) {
    previous = selected;
    selected = revues[current];
});
$scope.ajouterRevue = function (title, view) {
    view = view || title;
    revues.push({ title: title, content: view, disabled: false });
};
$scope.supprimerRevue = function (revue) {
    var index = revues.indexOf(revue);
    revues.splice(index, 1);
};

    //I'm using this function because in my actual form, I can not have all required fields filled in because I process several validation rules, and I use ng-if and ng-show to make appear or disappear some required fields. In brief, I use it to force validation of the form so that all the fields are valid (even if they are not filled).
    $scope.validRevueForm = function () {
        if ($scope.nomDemandeur && 
            $scope.prenomDemandeur &&
            $scope.emailDemandeur) {
                $scope.revueForm.$setValidity('required', true);
                return true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.revueForm.$setValidity('required', false);
            return false;
        }

    };

    //Submit Revue Form
    $scope.submitRevueForm = function () {
        if ($scope.validRevueForm() === true) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    //Submit List Revues Form
    $scope.submitSupportDemande = function () {
        if ($scope.submitRevueForm() === true) {
            alert('Support de demande envoyé avec succès');
            return true;
        }
    };


    //Tabs 'Revues'
    $scope.revues = [{
        id: 1,
        content: $scope.revue
    }]

    $scope.counter = 1;
    /** Function to add a new tab **/
    $scope.ajouterRevue = function () {
        $scope.counter++;
        $scope.revues.push({ id: $scope.counter, content: $scope.revue });
        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.revues.length - 1; //set the newly added tab active. 
    }

    /** Function to delete a tab **/
    $scope.supprimerRevue = function (index) {
        if ($scope.revues.length > 0) {
            $scope.revues.splice(index, 1); //remove the object from the array based on index
            $scope.counter--;
        }
    }

    $scope.selectedTab = 1; //set selected tab to the 1st by default.

    /** Function to set selectedTab **/
    $scope.selectTab = function (index) {
        $scope.selectedTab = index;
    }
}
```

SupportDemande.cs :

```
public class SupportDemande
{
    public List<Revue> GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Revue> revues = new List<Revue>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Revue revue = new Revue();
                revue.RevueID = i;
                //revue.RevueContent = "informations sur la revue " + i;
                revues.Add(revue);
            }
            return revues;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Revue.cs :

```
public class Revue
{
    public int RevueID { get; set; }
    public String Nom { get; set; }
    public String Prenom { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
}
```

SupportController.cs :

```
[Authorize]
[HandleError]
[RoutePrefix("Supports")]
public class SupportsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SupportDemande()
    {
        return View("SupportDemande");
    }

    //GET: /Supports/
    public JsonResult RevueData()
    {
        BEMF_REVUES.Models.SupportDemande supportDemande = new SupportDemande();
        var myList = supportDemande.GetData();
        return Json(myList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You can't submit multiple forms at once. You would need to dynamically combine all the data into one object and then submit that via AJAX or something. Alternatively, you can simply have one form tag that wraps all the tabs and then your tabs would just have their fields (not their own form tags).

Comment: Can you please show me how to do in code snippet ? I want to dynamically combine all the forms into one object and submit via REST Web API. By the way, I added .cs backend files in the question.